# Fedora26 PHP 7.1.10 PDO_SQLITE Startup Warning: Unable to load dynamic library

Tags: fedora, php7, sqlite, pdo

php -v responds with :

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64
>   /php/modules/pdo_sqlite.so' - /usr/lib64/php/modules/pdo_sqlite.so: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name in Unknown on line 0
>   PHP 7.1.10 (cli) (built: Sep 27 2017 05:17:09) ( NTS )
>   Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
>   Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
>      with Zend OPcache v7.1.10, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies

FC26 Server software is up to date.

```
**dnf info  php-pdo**
Last metadata expiration check: 4 days, 7:07:24 ago on Tue 17 Oct 2017 03:57:19 AM CDT.
Installed Packages
Name         : php-pdo
Version      : 7.1.10
Release      : 1.fc26
Arch         : x86_64
Size         : 385 k
Source       : php-7.1.10-1.fc26.src.rpm
Repo         : @System
From repo    : updates
Summary      : A database access abstraction module for PHP applications
URL          : http://www.php.net/
License      : PHP
Description  : The php-pdo package contains a dynamic shared object that will add
             : a database access abstraction layer to PHP.  This module provides
             : a common interface for accessing MySQL, PostgreSQL or other
             : databases.
```

Search terms: sqlite3, undefined symbol sqlite3 and other similarly worded google searches, forum  research, and PHP bugzilla searches all failed to produce any results offering a resolution for this particular startup complaint.

Have anyone encountered this "column_table_name" complaint before? or possibly, can someone point me to the location of the phantom database or table causing the startup complaint?

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you ever find a solution to remedy this warning?

Comment: This seems to be a bug in PHP from 2009, and it still has not been fixed: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48614